# ANDROID_MAJOR_VERSION for custom Android 12 ROM

Tags: kernel, samsung-mobile, android-12

I compile 3.10 Samsung kernel for Samsung SM A510F with custom Android 12 ROM installed. What letter I should put at the end of ANDROID_MAJOR_VERSION?

I got error

```
Makefile 155: Not found Android version file. Set none.
```

ANDROID_MAJOR_VERSION=q can be the right choice?